# Need to dispaly svg on an image in Xamarin

Tags: svg, xamarin.forms

I have an url that gets team logos but it returns svg   https://www.mlbstatic.com/team-logos/141.svg.

How can i display this in a Image for xamarin forms?

Searched and only found complex huge amounts of code.

looking for

1. Download image  -- I have this but what do i need to save it in GetResponsestream  preferrable i would like to stay in memory and not write to disk or file.
2. Attach it to an image to display.

Thanks.

Comment: use the FFImageLoading nuget - https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading

Comment: About your second point what's the purpose of attaching a svg to an image? To display what and where? You may clear up your question for people who want to help you can properly understand

Comment: @Jason I will try that, Thank you .

Comment: @SIMBIOSIS Sure, Attaching the image that is downloaded to an Xamarin image type would display that image to the user that is looking at the screen.  Hope that clears it up.

Comment: I still can't see the usefulness of such and attachment but if you say it is necessary then I do not what else to say.

Comment: Hey, don't be angry with me. Of course that an app with no images would be a nonesense. What I don't unsderstand is this 
    **1- Download image --....** and **2- Attach it to an image to display**. If my English is not wrong, the it in your **Attach it** of your second stament is refering to the image on **Download image** of your first statement. That's what cofuses me, why to download and image and the attach it to an image to display? But don't worry. Maybe someone will understand you and you'll get your answer. I was just tryng to help.

Comment: @SIMBIOSIS ok, i thought my answer to your question clarified it.  Have a great day.

Comment: Does  FFImageLoading work?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, thought i would post my solution here.

I used SkiSharp:

```
        SkiaSharp.Extended.Svg.SKSvg svg = new SkiaSharp.Extended.Svg.SKSvg();
        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
           // ie for theurl:  https://www.mlbstatic.com/team-logos/141.svg 
            svg.Load(new MemoryStream(client.DownloadData(new Uri(theurl))));



            var bitmap = new SKBitmap((int)svg.CanvasSize.Width, (int)svg.CanvasSize.Height);
            var canvas = new SKCanvas(bitmap);
            canvas.DrawPicture(svg.Picture);
            canvas.Flush();
            canvas.Save();

            string filename = "";
            using (var image = SKImage.FromBitmap(bitmap))
            using (var data = image.Encode(SKEncodedImageFormat.Png, 80))
            {
                

                // save the data to a stream
                 filename = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "temp.png");
                
                using (var stream = File.OpenWrite(filename ))
                {
                    data.SaveTo(stream);
                }
                
            }

            
        }
```

use FileName from above to assign source to Xamarin image.

this accomplished the task with the least amount of code lines i tried.